# An Integral Inequality Question

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals, absolute-value

> We have the functions $f$ and $g$ such that,
>
> $$f:\mathbb{[0,1]}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
>
> $$g:\mathbb{[0,1]}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
>
> and both $f$ and $g$ are bounded and continuos functions. Show that,
>
> $$\int_0^1 |f(x) + g(x)|\:dx \: \le \int_0^1 |f(x)| \:dx + \int_0^1 |g(x)| \:dx $$

Could anyone help me out on this one ?

Comment: As written, this is false. Take $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = -x$. Do you mean $\leq$

Comment: I think the OP means $\le$.

Comment: Hint: for all real numbers, $a$ and $b$, $| a + b| \leq |a| + |b|$

Comment: harder question: can our over-eager solvers wait until Monk responds to Simon's hint?

Comment: @SimonS That would mean $|f(x) + g(x)|\: \le |f(x)| +  |g(x)| $ , but I don't see how the inequality is preserved after we integrate ?

Comment: If $h$ and $k$ are integrable functions such that $h(x) \geq k(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, then $h(x) - k(x) \geq 0$ and it is indeed the case that $$\int_0^1 (h(x) - k(x)) \ dx \geq 0$$ Thus $$\int_0^1 h(x) \ dx \geq \int_0^1 k(x) \ dx$$

Comment: @SimonS Thanks ! I get it now !

Comment: One more technicality, which may or may not be important depending on your course. Why do any of the integrals in your question exist?

Comment: @SimonS Well, in the context I encountered the problem - these are Riemann-Integrals . Do we mean to say we should first show that these are Riemann Integrable ?

Comment: If that's the kind of thing you're expected to do, yes. I've written out an argument below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the technicality discussed above:

As $f$ and $g$ are continuous on a closed interval $[0,1]$, the integrals $\int_0^1 f(x) \ dx$, $\int_0^1 g(x) \ dx$ exist by standard results.

Further, $|f|$ is also a continuous function on $[0,1]$ because it is the composite of two continuous functions, $f$ and absolute value $| \cdot |$. Hence $|f|$ is integrable on $[0,1]$. Likewise for $|g|$.

Finally, $|f + g|$ is also continuous, being the composite of the sum of two continuous  functions--which is also continuous--and absolute value; thus $\int_0^1 |f(x) + g(x)| \ dx$ also exists.